# Comparing Sympy factor results false

Tags: python, comparison, sympy, factoring

I've found an issue about Sympy that I can't understand.

Why does this return false...

```
factor(81*q + 90) == 9*(9*q + 10)
```

... whilst this returns true?

```
factor(q**2-64) == (q+8)*(q-8)
```

When I type

```
factor(81*q + 90)
```

the output is exactly this expression

```
9*(9*q + 10)
```

So, why doesn't Sympy consider my first comparison is true?

Answer (score 1):

SymPy automatically distributes `number*addition`, like `9*(9*q + 10)` into `81*q + 90`. `factor` uses a trick to prevent this automatic simplification (basically, `Mul(9, 9*q + 10, evaluate=False)`).

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/4596) to remove this automatic simplification, but it hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you have any ideia on how I could verify whether an input string is totally factored  or not?

Comment: I think the only way is to check if `factor(expr) == expr`.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work in cases like this: `factor(81*q + 90) == 9*(9*q + 10)`

Comment: If you are starting out with expr as a string you can use `sympify(string, evaluate=False)` to convert it to an expression without distributing the constants (or any other evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

[From docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs)

You may do as below:

```
factor(81*q + 90).equals(9*(9*q + 10))
```